# Measure word for a war / long campaign?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was trying to figure out if there is a suitable word for a sentence along the lines of the following:

> The Battle of ABC was one of the more ideologically complex ________
> of the Crusades.

In this case, the larger 'war' or 'campaign' is the [Crusades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crusades). It's certainly not a series, since it's just one event. Perhaps 'episode' would be appropriate here? But at the same time, it seems a bit generic. 'Skirmish' captures the military context, but seems to come across as a bit repititive: after all, we already used the word 'battle.' Plus skirmish tends to imply a smaller incident, and may trivialize the event when I don't mean too. Ideally, there would be a measure word that sounds both academic and suited for the military.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the prior comments rejecting certain words, I would go with *operation*. This term is used frequently contemporarily, but would be quite the anachronism to apply to the crusades. It does encompass a large scope, larger than a theater, which may be what you're looking for. A less anachronistic term would probably be *offensive*, which obviously cannot be applied arbitrarily and whose use depends on the point of view which you are expressing the event.

On a side note, a skirmish very specific and not a synonym for 'battle' and I hope you're not using it that way.